# Excel returning a non zero value for something that should be zero

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using this formula:

```
=IF(Data!F26>=0.875, "aaa", "")
```

The value in Data!F26 is blank or ""

The cell displays aaa when it should be blank because 0 or blank or "" is less than .875. In my actual sheet aaa is a formula that then returns #Value as an error.

[image: My excel formula that isn't doing what I expect]

[image: The formula and value in Data!F26]

Comment: I will be using a formula like `=IF(Data!F26="","",IF(Data!F26>=0.875,"aaa",""))` this is because in Excel a text value(even a space " ") will be evaluated as greater than any number.

Comment: To add to @MayukhBhattacharya explanation, Excel will also evaluate the null string `""` as text and consider it greater than a numerical value.  You could also try `=IF(OR(ISTEXT(Data!F26),Data!F26>=0.875),"aaa","")`

Comment: Note that floating point numbers are a bit tricky, what looks like a perfectly finite number of decimals may well be similar to 1/3 in base ten. 0.875 is actually very similar to 1/3 in the fact that computers believe it to end with an infinite number of "9". Techincalities: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic - `python -c "from decimal import *;getcontext().prec=100;print(1 / ( 1/Decimal('0.875') ) )"` will print 95 `9`s after `0.874`

Comment: You can also use `=IF(N(Data!F26)>=0.875,"aaa","")`. `N` function acts as a number filter and converts non-numbers to `0`. Unfortunately, this does not apply to error values.